# How to adjust the distance between footnote and text in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, footnotes

As what I show in the following picture. The `\footnote` index is too far from the content which is "database" in the picture. It seems there is a space betweeen them but indeed not. Is there any method that helps to narrow the distance?

[image: Examples]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You might want to show the tex code that generates this picture.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I had to put a   or `~` in front of `\footnote` to produce that unwanted space:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
distributed NoSQL database\footnote{abc}.

distributed NoSQL database.\footnote{abc}

distributed NoSQL database \footnote{abc}.

distributed NoSQL database~\footnote{abc}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I always put a `~` in front of `\footnote`, and it is unnecessary.